# Monstera deliciousa brown residue on STEMS?

Tags: diseases, pests, monstera, stems

[image: Monstera with brown scars on stems]

I have a fairly mature monstera deliciousa, that has been thriving and putting out new growth. I moved it into my bathroom for the winter.

It’s now spring so I brought it outside and noticed this brown residue on the stems only. It can be scraped off somewhat easily and I’m wondering what this is, if it’s bad, or what.

Everything I am finding online only talks about brown spots on the leaf. I can’t seem to find any info on this.